# SSL handshake failure | Client hello(success) -> Server ACK (success) -> server RST (connection closed)

Tags: tls, x.509, tcp, handshake, mqtt

I was running MQTT broker in my pc and tried to connect to it via mqtt client in same PC. using x509 cert for mutual tls. SSL Handshake was failing with RST from server. This was happening only in my PC.
When I tried to do the same setup in VM running in my PC, it works. Not sure what's going wrong. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this.

**Wireshark logs:**

```
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TCP 56  56793 → 8883 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=1 SACK_PERM
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TCP 56  8883 → 56793 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TCP 44  56793 → 8883 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TLSv1.2 197 Client Hello
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TCP 44  8883 → 56793 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=154 Win=2161152 Len=0
192.168.1.12    192.168.1.12    TCP 44  8883 → 56793 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=154 Win=0 Len=0
```

**Client hello (from failure PC):**

```
    Transport Layer Security
        TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Content Type: Handshake (22)
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Length: 148
            Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
                Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
                Length: 144
                Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
                Random: 6415564f8d4243a378676945ae90bcdd3865458b456e3c2b82d1e3fc46832daa
                Session ID Length: 0
                Cipher Suites Length: 42
                Cipher Suites (21 suites)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                    Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Compression Methods Length: 1
                Compression Methods (1 method)
                Extensions Length: 61
                Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
                Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
                Extension: signature_algorithms (len=26)
                Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
                Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
                Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                [JA3 Fullstring: 771,49196-49195-49200-49199-49188-49187-49192-49191-49162-49161-49172-49171-157-156-61-60-53-47-56-158-159,10-11-13-35-23-65281,29-23-24,0]
                [JA3: 1a2e744230d93b103604fc70cf0ba509]
```

**Client hello (from success PC):**

```
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 148
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 144
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 64154e9a612aca60229078178df4ce178d9eabaea00dded4ccc99dc6fbc8108a
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 42
            Cipher Suites (21 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
            Extensions Length: 61
            Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=26)
            Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
            Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
            [JA3 Fullstring: 771,49196-49195-49200-49199-159-158-49188-49187-49192-49191-49162-49161-49172-49171-157-156-61-60-53-47-10,10-11-13-35-23-65281,29-23-24,0]
            [JA3: c12f54a3f91dc7bafd92cb59fe009a35]
```

Comment: Certificate is not relevant here yet since it is not transferred. It breaks after the ClientHello already. One reason might be that the server does not like the ClientHello compared to what you send to the other machine - only nothing is known about the difference of these and what the server expects. Or there might be some middleware intercepting the traffic in the non-working case and breaking it , i.e. something like a firewall. Too much unknowns here to help. Check also the server logs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I cross verified cipher list in both client hello and it looks similar. I will update that in question. Can you help me on how best we can troubleshoot the middlewares?

Comment: Do a packet capture at the server side and check if the RST gets actually created by the server. If yes - then it is some problem in the server and you should check the logs. If no - then something in the middle interfered with the connection and you need to check your network environment on what this might be.

Comment: Is there any tool to trace network packets from process in loopback adapter? Since both server and client are in same PC, I am just trying to trace packet for particular process. Any suggestions?

Comment: if they communicate through the loopback device there is unlikely something in between. So it is more likely that the server does not like the ClientHello. Note that there are way more things to watch for than the ciphers itself. What is visible is that the JA3 fingerprint of the ClientHello is different - due to a different order of ciphers.  What cipher was chosen by the server in the successful setup?

Comment: I investigated in server side and found that tls was not enabled (checked via sslscan.exe) though I am enabling while starting server. Will investigate further on server side. Thanks @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Also some settings in my system are restricting the server from enabling ssl I guess. That too when started via specific certificate. with other certificate it works. Any leads on this?

Comment: If it works inside the VM but not on your PC then please compare the relevant setups. Nothing in your question provides any information, of what the difference in setups might be.